# Hybrid solution: SharePoint with lower cost storage

Tags: integration, file-server, hybrid

We're a medium-sized consulting engineering firm with a lot of files organized by project. Project files are a mix of MS Office documents and larger technical data (CAD models, measurement data, etc).

We love Sharepoint for working with Office documents; the collaboration features, high availability, and durability are worth the price. We can't afford to house all our data in Sharepoint, however, due to the larger technical data previously mentioned.

We don't need the durability, availability, and collaboration features of Sharepoint for technical data and we don't want to split our projects apart - forcing employees to navigate differently depending on the nature of the files they need to access.

Is there a solution that allows office files to live in Sharepoint, and technical data in lower-cost storage solutions (e.g. on-prem fileserver) but which presents all files together seamlessly in the user interface?

I suspect there may be enterprise-grade solutions for this, but remember we're a medium-sized shop.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for an OnPrem solution and still use the SharePoint features, I would suggest having a look at the `Record or Document Center` in SharePoint that can hold data for 4 Tera.

**Read more at**

- [Create Record Center](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-records-center-6bf1488b-62a8-486c-90dd-54b6bcce4b3a)
- [Create Document Center](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/what-is-a-document-center-site-06096070-d83f-45b8-b02d-ec7a4cf85cac)

Otherwise, I would suggest SFTP, and showing your files in SharePoint through External List or any other third-party tool.